# CSS Toggling a submenu in DevExtreme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, devextreme

I would like to toggle a submenu in my mobile application when clicking a link, but when clicking the submenu doesn't show on top of the content div. The code is simple but I can't figure out what's wrong:

HTML:

```
<div class="home-view"  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
    <div class="side-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="menu-link" data-bind="click: showMenu" href="#">Offres</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="side-sub-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Offres</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="view-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.home-view p {
    padding: 5px;
}

#menu-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.side-sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30%;
    background-color: orange;
    max-width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.side-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
    max-width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
}

.view-content {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    showMenu: function () {
        $(".side-sub-menu").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
};
return viewModel;
```

Result (Before clicking): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETqTQ.png 
Result (After clicking): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV6vM.png

PS: I tried to make a fiddle but it didn't work as in the DevExtreme simulator.

Comment: You want your submenu to display directly sticked to your menu ? First, consider adding a real width (not only max-width) to your .side-menu, and position:relative to your home-view

Comment: The `position:relative` doesn't change anything, I removed to max-width, and set `left: 11%` to the .side-sub-menu class. It got me close so I'm thinking this is a positioning problem, could you tell how can I set view-content just beside the side-menu div and how can I make the side-sub-menu div showing on top of the view-content div.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve your problem only by css. It's a positioning problem. Set a fixed with to your side-menu, then set a fixed width to your submenu and give its left value the widt of your side-menu. Then play with z-indexes to display submenu on top of your view content:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.home-view {
    position:relative;
}
.home-view p {
    padding: 5px;
}

#menu-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.side-sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15%;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index:11;
}

.side-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
}

.view-content {
    position:absolute;
    left: 15%;
    top: 0;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: The z-index did the trick, I don't know how it slipped out of my mind.
Thank you Robin :)